# My canvas is not drawing all the rectangles im trying to draw

Tags: java, android

Ive checked similar questions here but the answers are doing what im doing already. Ive tried most of the things i can think of and just cant solve it.

I created my own view where i draw rectangles 100x100 in size next to eachother. The first rectangle is drawn correctly but the second is drawn in the color of the third rectangle and the third rectangle is not drawn at all. I just cant figure out what im doing wrong.

```
private void init(@Nullable AttributeSet set){
        listRect = new ArrayList<>();
        listColor = new ArrayList<>();
        loadRect();
        invalidate();
    }

    private void loadRect(){
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        rect.set(0,0,100,100);
        listColor.add(paint);
        listRect.add(rect);


        rect = new Rect();
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        rect.set(100,0,100,100);
        listColor.add(paint);
        listRect.add(rect);

        rect = new Rect();
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        rect.set(200,0,100,100);
        listColor.add(paint);
        listRect.add(rect);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        for(int i = 0; i < listRect.size(); i++){
            canvas.drawRect(listRect.get(i), listColor.get(i));
        }
    }
```

[image: Here is a image of the layout view]

Comment: Same for Rect #2. You should change `rect.set(100,0,100,100);` to `rect.set(100,0,200,100);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rect` [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect#Rect(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) takes 4 arguments:

```java
public Rect (int left, 
                int top, 
                int right, 
                int bottom)
```

Same for the `set` [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect#set(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)):

```java
public void set (int left, 
                int top, 
                int right, 
                int bottom)
```

So your last rectangle is not correct (I mean `right`):

```
rect.set(200,0,100,100);
```

It should be:

```
rect.set(200,0,300,100);
```